# Viewing a windows 8/10 HDD on Linux GParted "Unrecognized Disk Label"

Tags: linux, windows, external-hard-drive

I have a relative who passed away and his wife wants to get all the family pictures and data from the HD. He was the only one who ever used it, we can't figure out the password. So I figure just pull the hard drive, right? Access the drive from my Linux laptop and copy all the data she needs. 
No.

When I plug the drive in (via USB external drive enclosure ) and appears under /dev/sdb

[code]sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb /media/ntfs
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way?[/code]

Open gParted; click on sdb says the entire drive is unallocated and in the info section says "Unrecognized Disk Label"

I googled around for a few answers and most of what I found was people working with dual-booting. I don't want to dual boot, frankly, I don't even care if it boots I just want to copy all the data and wipe it.

Comment: Is the drive encrypted?

Comment: "we can't figure out the password" the password to the PC? Or the hard disk?

Comment: try another USB enclosure or connecting directly to your motherboard.  if that USB enclosure is bad it might be corrupting the drive's data (including making the partition table unreadable).

Comment: note your mount command would not work in ordinary circumstances; `/dev/sdb` is the whole drive, and usually you need to mount a partition like `/dev/sdb1`.

Comment: To clarify, the drive is NOT encrypted, NOT bitlocked, we don't have the normal account password, he was the only user. I don't have another enclosure at the moment but I've tried other drives without issue.

Comment: You might try booting from GNU/Linux (even live media) and try the following commands in an effort to determine the layout of the drive.  1)  `sudo fdisk -l -u`  2) `sudo blkid` and 3) `sudo parted -l` and then look for the device or partition path that represents the USB hard drive.  From there you can hopefully determine if you need to mount a partition or whole disk device.